Visualization of skew-symmetric rank-2 tensor fields
Background
I was reading Einstein's The Meaning of Relativity in which he points out that axial vectors are usually used in place of rank $2$ tensors for the sake of geometrical picturisation, as in the "moment of force" (pg.$19$, eq. ($15$)), defined by a tensor equation:
$$\frac {d}{dt}\left[ m(\xi_\mu\dot\xi_\nu - \xi_\nu\dot\xi_\mu) \right]=\xi_\mu X_\nu-\xi_\nu X_\mu\equiv A_{\mu \nu}$$
Where $\textbf{ξ}=(\xi_\nu)$ is the position vector, $\mathbf X=(X_\nu)$ is the force vector and $\mathbf A=(A_{\mu \nu})$ is the moment tensor of rank $2$. We equivalently write: 
$$\frac{d}{dt}(m\textbf{ξ}\times\dot{\mathbf ξ})=\textbf{ξ}\times \mathbf X\equiv \mathbf A'$$
where the RHS is an (axial) vector quantity $A'_\mu=\frac{1}{2} A_{\sigma \tau}\epsilon_{\sigma \tau \mu}$. He further shows that the stress tensor is symmetric: $$p_{\mu \nu}=p\delta_{\mu \nu}-\alpha\left[ \left( \frac{\partial u_\mu}{\partial x_\nu}+\frac{\partial u_\nu}{\partial x_\mu}\right)-\frac{2}{3}\frac{\partial u_\alpha}{\partial x_\alpha} \delta_{\mu \nu}\right]$$
And the magnetic field $\mathbf h$ is a skew symmetric tensor $(h_{\mu \nu})$ defined by the Maxwell equation:
$$\frac{\partial e_\mu}{\partial x_\nu}-\frac{\partial e_\nu}{\partial x_\mu} = \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial h_{\mu \nu}}{\partial t}$$
Visual Representation of Tensor Fields
While scalar fields can be viewed as iso-surfaces and vector field as stream-lines with directional components at each point in the space where the field exists, trouble arises with tensors. While symmetric tensors of rank $2$ can be visualized by "Hyper-streamlines" rendered as 
tubes with elliptic cross section, 
radii proportional to $2^\text{nd}$ and $3^\text{rd}$
eigenvalue , this is possible only because the corresponding symmetric matrix $Q$ can be mapped to a quadratic form $\mathbf x^T Q \mathbf x$ which gives an ellipsoid or hyperboloid surface of revolution at each point in space, with its axes oriented in the directions of the eigenvectors of $Q$, which are orthogonal in an $\mathbb R^3$ space. On the other hand the eigenvalues of a completely antisymmetric $3\times 3$ matrix are imaginary viz. if $H=[h_{\mu \nu}]$ be antisymmetric $(H=-H^T)$, then the eigenvalues are $\{-jh,+jh,0\}$ where $h=\sqrt{\sum h_{\mu \nu}^2}$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are of the form :
$$
\mathbf v_1 = \mathbf x - j\mathbf y \in \mathbb C^3,$$ $$ \mathbf v_2 = \mathbf x + j\mathbf y = \mathbf v_1^* \in \mathbb C^3$$ $$ \mathbf v_3 \in \mathbb R^3
$$
The quadratic form is $\mathbf z^T H \mathbf z=0$. What I am trying to do is to find an equivalent of the principal axis theorem for anti-symmetric matrices which can describe geometrical pipelike structures embedded in $\mathbb C^3$ rather than $\mathbb R^3$. Till now I have only heard about "symplectic forms" which involve anti-symmetric tensors (still trying to understand).
Some relevant links are:

https://www-apr.lip6.fr/~tierny/stuff/teaching/tierny_visualization_tensorFields.pdf

https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9707140

Hyperstreamline


